# How divide the database up into into smaller databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a big SQL Server 2012 database.

I want to split it into preferences and data.

However I find that SQL Server does not seem to support the idea of dividing your data up into object oriented databases. It seems to rely on everything being in the same database.

For example foreign keys are not supported in database. Also cross database joins are a real pain to do.

How would someone typically go about doing this? Is it just a limitation of SQL Server that I should use the same DB for everything?

Comment: this can be a classical case of "doing things wrong". Why would you want to do such thing to yourself and somebody who will inherit this system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQl Server provides partitioning feature. As per [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28database%29)

A partition is a division of a logical database or its constituting elements into distinct independent parts. Database partitioning is normally done for manageability, performance or availability reasons

```
1.Horizontal partitioning
2.Vertical partitioning

Each has it is own file group.it can be configured
```

***Visit this links that should help***

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178148%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

[SQLAuthority](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/01/25/sql-server-2005-database-table-partitioning-tutorial-how-to-horizontal-partition-database-table/)

I am sure there are plenty of tutorials out there.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server is a *relational* database, so there really shouldn't be an expectation that it would support a fundamentally different architecture implied by an *object or object-oriented* database.

I don't understand your comment that "foreign keys are not supported in database." Foreign keys are all part of the integrity constraints in SQL Server, and a detail description of how to create them is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189049.aspx)

I think you might want to be more specific about the type of data you're trying to split up, and why you want to put them in physically separate databases. A refinement of your problem might help us provide better answers.

Comment: Not sure about SQL Server, but Oracle allows to define object tables in which each record is also an object. The fields of the records are properties of an object, bringing object database and relational database very much together.